# Не находит точку входа в программу

Tags: java

Выполняю тестовые задания в книге по Java и не могу разобраться:
если интерфейс объявлен в одном файле с классом компилятор пытается найти метод у интерфейса.

```
interface Aquatic 
{
  public default int getNumberOfGills(int input) {
  return input;
  }
}
public class ClownFish implements Aquatic {
  public String getNumberOfGills() { return "4"; }
  public int getNumberOfGills(int input) { return 6; }
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
   System.out.println(new ClownFish().getNumberOfGills(-1));
  }
}
```

Следовательно, я получаю ошибку:

> error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Aquatic

Если я пытаюсь вынести интерфейс в отдельный файл Aquatic.java компилятор его не видит:

```
test.java:1: error: cannot find symbol
public class ClownFish implements Aquatic {
                                  ^
  symbol: class Aquatic
```

Что не так?

Comment: все не так, раз не работает

Comment: замените интерфес на абстрактный класс и будет рабоать

Comment: в интерфейсе методы (их тела не пишутся)

Comment: >в интерфейсе методы (их тела не пишутся)
но компилятор не ругается на это

Comment: Можно и названия класса с маленькой буквы писать. Но вся суть в том, что для заполненных методов есть абстрактные классы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня все работает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
, хотя сам NetBeans предлагает перенести `interface` в допустимую папку или файл.
Также работает и с абстрактным классом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
abstract class Aquatic 
{
  public int getNumberOfGills(int input) {
  return input;
  }
}
public class ClownFish extends  Aquatic {
  public String getNumberOfGills() { return "4"; }
  public int getNumberOfGills(int input) { return 6; }
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
   System.out.println(new ClownFish().getNumberOfGills(-1));
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, может проблема в компиляторе тогда, пишу в блокноте, компилирую в консоли.

Comment: @gerodothche лайкните ответ, примите, если помог - мне будет очень приятно)

Answer (score 0):

Вы использовали default метод в интерфейсе, они, вместе с лямбдами, появились в Java 8, раз у вас не компилируется, значит у вас версия jdk <8.
Только что скопировал ваш код в ClownFish.java и запустил

```
javac ClownFish.java
java ClownFish
> 6

java -version
> openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25
```

Comment: у меня 11 версия

Comment: Значит у тебя проблема в настройки окружения. Я добился ошибки "error: cannot find symbol" определив переменную окружения CLASSPATH с неверным значением, такой переменной по умолчанию вовсе не должно быть. Переменная окружения будет использоваться если явно не задать путь к classpath через ключ cp с путем к директории в которой файлы с исходниками, попробуй собрать так: 

*javac -cp . ClownFish.java* и
*java -cp . ClownFish*